# How would I go about finding the 'flag' in this QR image(Capture the Flag)?

Tags: security

[image: The QR image]

How do I find the flag in this QR image? After scanning the QR image, I obtain the following text which may be of help: N2QzNjYyMzQ2NDMzMzMzMzM3MzAzNDM0NjEzMzMyNjEzNjM2Mzk2NTY2MzQ2NDMwMzgzODMyMzQz
MzM4MzAzNTYyN2I2NzYxNmM2Ng==

What have you obtained as the flag and how? Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: The == at the end is a strong hint at base64 encoding. Have you tried decoding it?

Comment: And what did you do to try to get it ?!

Comment: i used base64 decoding but suspected there was one more conversion to finding the flag

Answer (score 2):

Its a base64 that once decoded will give you a HEX string, that if converted to chars will let you find your reversed flag string:

Redacted reversed flag:
}6b4d**********05b{galf

Redacted flag is:
flag{b508**********3d4b6}

Comment: @soufiane :(  it was easy enough i dont think you should have provided anything more than hint igorsk already gave him a hint

Comment: @blabb you're right :/ I think he found me in a good mood lol